# Can Html iframe tag have source from a html encoded text string?

Tags: html, iframe, blazor-client-side

Is it possible for html tag `<iframe>` to have a src attribute coming from a string of text that containts html tags? If yes, can you please give sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my question.
This is possible with the use of `srcdoc` attribute. Thus,

`<iframe srcdoc=""></iframe>`

Comment: FWIW, `srcdoc` is not supported in any version of IE and original Edge (not Chromium Edge).  That should be an ever lessening concern now that Windows 7 is EOL and Microsoft is pushing Chromium Edge out in Windows 10. Still, it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Oh... thank you for the info, I consider that as well.